# Convert curves to monotone curves without introduce intersections

Tags: general-topology

All functions are continuous. For $f:A\to X\times Y$, we define $f_x$ and $f_y$ such that $f(t) = (f_x(t),f_y(t))$.

$I=[0,1]$ is the unit interval. A complete curve $f:I\to I\times Y$ is a simple curve with $f_x(t)=t$ for $t\in\{0,1\}$

I am interested in the question

> $f,g:I\to I\times Y$ are complete curves and $f(I)\cap g(I) = \emptyset$
>   . Does there always exist a strictly monotonically
>   increasing homeomorphism $h:I\to I$, such that $f^*(t) = (t,f_y(t))$,
>   and $g^*(t) = (h(t),g_y(t))$, and $f^* (I)\cap g^* (I)$ is empty?

If $Y=I$, then I have a proof which essentially uses the Jordan curve theorem. [Here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/208263198) is a proof sketch for the harder part of the proof.

I wonder if this holds in general.

Comment: I don't understand the question. what $g^*$ and $f^*$ are? as is written it seems that h(t)=t works.

Comment: $g^*$ and $f^*$ are just two complete curves defined in terms of $f,g$ and $h$. $h(t)=t$ doesn't always work as there might be a intersection. For example this graph. http://i.imgur.com/HF1FNgk.png We can parametrize $f$ and $g$ so at time $t$, both $f_y(t) = g_y(t)$(with different $x$ coordinate). If $h(t)=t$, then $g^*(t)=f^*(t)$, so there is a intersection.

Comment: but in your hypothesis I read $f(I)\cap g(I)=\emptyset$

Comment: $f(I)\cap g(I)=\emptyset$ does not imply $f_y(I)\cap g_y(I) = \emptyset$.

Comment: but $f(I)\cap g(I)=\emptyset$ and $h(t)=t$ implies $f^*=f$ and $g^*=g$, hence $f^*(I)\cap g^*(I)=\emptyset$

Comment: h(t)=t does not imply g*=g, neither does it imply f*=f.

Comment: I think I don't understand something. You said that $f=(f_x,f_y)$ and that $f_x(t)=t$, so $f(t)=(t,f_y(t))$. Then you said $f^∗=(t,f_y(t))$ right?. So $f=f^∗$ always. As for $g$, you say $g^∗=(h(t),g_y(t))$. Thus if $h(t)=t$,then also $g=g^∗$.

Comment: $f_x(t)=t$ for $t=0$ and $t=1$, not all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: ooooooooooooook! I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always possible. The following is a counterexample.

Let $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$ and let $I=[0,1]$, as usual. Now, define $$Y = S^1\cup (I\times\{0\}),$$ i.e. a circle with a "hair". Let $$\phi:[0,1]\to S^1, \phi(t)=(\cos2\pi t,\sin2\pi t)$$ be the usual parametrization of the circle. We will define $f$ and $g$ by explicit formulas: $$f(t)=\begin{cases}(t,\phi(t+\frac12));&t\in[0,\frac12],\\
(t,\phi(t-\frac12));&t\in[\frac12,1],\end{cases}$$ and $$g(t)=\begin{cases}(2t,\phi(2t+\frac14));&t\in[0,\frac38],\\
(\frac32-2t,(-2t+\frac74,0));&t\in[\frac38,\frac12],\\
(\frac32-2t,(2t-\frac14,0));&t\in[\frac12,\frac58],\\
(2t-1,\phi(2t-\frac54));&t\in[\frac58,1].\end{cases}$$

It is easily verified that $f(I)\cap g(I)=\emptyset$. Also, note that $f^*=f$. Now, we will argue by contradiction. Suppose the homeomorphism $h$ (and thus $g^*$) exists, as in the question. The following inequalities are easy to verify: $$h(\frac38)>\frac12>h(\frac58).$$ (If the first one fails, we have $f^*([0,\frac12])\cap g^*([0,\frac38])\neq\emptyset$ and if the second one fails, we have $f^*([\frac12,1])\cap g^*([\frac58,1])\neq\emptyset$, by the intermediate value theorem.)

But this is a contradiction: $h$ was supposed to be strictly increasing. (I hope I have some more time later to include some pictures.)

Answer (score -3):

Just as an addition to @dejan-govc. 
Here is the mathematica code to plot $f$ and $g$.

[image]

Since there is no depth perception here it's not obvious there is no intersections, but one can run the code himself and see the 3D image.

```
Phi[t_] := {Cos[2*Pi t], Sin[2*Pi t]};
f[t_] := Piecewise[
   {
    {Join[{t}, Phi[t + 1/2]], 0 <= t < 1/2},
    {Join[{t}, Phi[t - 1/2]], 1/2 <= t < 1}
    }];
g[t_] := Piecewise[
   {
    {Join[{2 t}, Phi[2 t + 1/4]], 0 <= t < 3/8},
    {Join[{3/2 - 2 t}, {-2 t + 7/4, 0}], 3/8 <= t < 1/2},
    {Join[{3/2 - 2 t}, {2 t - 1/4, 0}], 1/2 <= t < 5/8},
    {Join[{2 t - 1}, Phi[2 t - 5/4]], 5/8 <= t <= 1}
    }];
ParametricPlot3D[{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```